# Deriving rotational energy of a disk via integration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, rotation

This is my attempt at deriving the exact formula for the rotational energy of a disk.

Let the disk have radius $R > 0$, mass $m > 0$, angular velocity of rotation $\omega > 0$, and the constant density $\rho = m / (\pi R^2)$. Now, consider the area element $\mathrm{d}A = r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\alpha$. The mass of that area element is given by
$$\mathrm{d}m = \rho \, \mathrm{d}A = \frac{mr \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\alpha}{\pi R^2}.$$
Next, the energy of that area is given by
$$\mathrm{d}E = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{d}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{d}m(r\omega)^2 = \frac{mr^3 \omega^2  \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\alpha}{2\pi R^2}.$$

Finally, the rotational energy is
\begin{aligned}
E_{rotational} &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R \mathrm{d}E \\
               &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R \frac{mr^3 \omega^2 }{2\pi R^2} \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\alpha\\
               &= \frac{m\omega^2}{2\pi R^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R r^3 \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\alpha \\
               &= \frac{m\omega^2}{2\pi R^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \Bigg[ \frac{1}{4} r^4 \Bigg]_{r = 0}^{r = R} \mathrm{d}\alpha \\
               &= \frac{m\omega^2R^2}{8\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\alpha \\
               &= \frac{m\omega^2R^2}{8\pi} \Bigg[\alpha\Bigg]_{\alpha = 0}^{\alpha = 2\pi} \\
               &= \frac{1}{4}m\omega^2R^2.
\end{aligned}

As you can see, I have an error by the factor of two. Where my calculation goes wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. $I = \frac{1}{2}mR^2$ and rotational energy is $E = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 = \frac{1}{4}mR^2\omega^2$.